# Translating the Rubberduck - Übersetzen der Gummiente - Part 1: Modelling

Tags: java, xml, i18n, rubberduck

So I have committed to making a German translation for the guys over at [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), which is localized via .resx files.
Now these files are basically XML-Files with a certain, rather simple document structure:

```
<root>
   <!-- Snip -->
   <data name="Resource_Key">
       <value>Resource Value</value>
   </data>
   <!-- Snip -->
</root>
```

Of course there's a little more to it, but as of now the program doesn't have to handle this.

The basic goal is:

1. Parse the resx-file into a DOM-Structure
2. Use said DOM-Structure to present a side-by-side view of Resource Values
3. Allow editing one side of the Resource Pair (that you translate into)
4. And save the whole thing back into the resx-File

I decided on a Presenter-First MVP approach, to develop this in a testable and extensible manner. This gives 4 rather massive interfaces to work upon:

```
public interface OverviewModel {
    void register(OverviewPresenter p);
    void loadFromDirectory(Path resxFolder, String targetLocale);
    List<Translation> getTranslations();
    Translation getSingleTranslation(String key);
    void updateTranslation(String key, String newTranslation);
    void save();
}
```

---

```
public interface OverviewPresenter {

    public static final String DEFAULT_TARGET_LOCALE = "de";
    public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_LOCALE = "";

    void show();
    void initialize();
    void loadFiles(Path resxFolder, String rootLocale, String targetLocale);
    void onException(Exception e, String message);
    void onParseCompletion();
    void onTranslationSubmit(Translation t);
    void onTranslateRequest(String key);
    void onTranslationAbort();
    void onSaveRequest();
}
```

---

```
public interface OverviewView {
    void register(OverviewPresenter p);
    void initialize();
    void show();
    void rebuildWith(List<Translation> translations);
    void showError(String title, String errorMessage);
}
```

Why 4 and not 3, as MVP would suggest? Because the editing is happening in a separated view. This view consists of a Label, a Textbox and 2 Buttons. This is the reason that there is only a Presenter for that part. It's basically a Popup dialog and that's why it has following `@implNote` in the javadoc:

> Implementation will not happen with an additional separated View
>   interface, since there is in no way enough View-Logic to justify it

So here (to clean up on the interface side) comes the `TranslationPresenter`:

```
public interface TranslationPresenter {
    public void register(OverviewPresenter p);
    public void show();
    public void hide();
    public void setRequestedTranslation(Translation t);
}
```

Now this all is just the skeleton of what is yet to come. Cramping the whole program into a single post would not make for good reviewable material though, 
so without further ado, here comes the part worrying me the most:

```
public class OverviewModelImpl implements OverviewModel {

    private static final String VALUE_NAME = "value";

    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    private static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "data";

    private static final String FILE_NAME_FORMAT = "RubberduckUI%s.resx";

    private final Map<String, String> originalLocale = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private final ExecutorService fileOperationService = Executors
            .newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private final BiConsumer<Path, Boolean> loadResxFile = (path, isTarget) -> {
        SAXBuilder documentBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        try {
            if (isTarget) {
                this.translationDocument = documentBuilder.build(path.toFile());
            } else {
                Document doc = documentBuilder.build(path.toFile());
                List<Element> translationElements = doc.getRootElement()
                        .getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);

                translationElements.stream().forEach(
                        element -> {
                            originalLocale.put(element.getAttribute(KEY_NAME)
                                    .getValue(), element
                                    .getChildText(VALUE_NAME));
                        });
            }
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            this.presenter.onException(e, "Unspecified Parsing error");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.presenter.onException(e, "Unspecified I/O Error");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.presenter.onException(e, "Something went really wrong");
        }
    };
    private final XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.instance();

    private OverviewPresenter presenter;
    private Document translationDocument;
    private Path currentPath;
    private String currentTargetLocale;

    @Override
    public void register(final OverviewPresenter p) {
        presenter = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadFromDirectory(final Path resxFolder,
            final String targetLocale) {
        this.currentPath = resxFolder;
        this.currentTargetLocale = targetLocale;
        // for now there's only en-US root-Files
        final Path rootFile = resxFolder.resolve(fileNameString(""));
        final Path targetFile = resxFolder
                .resolve(fileNameString(targetLocale));

        Runnable buildDocument = () -> {
            originalLocale.clear();
            loadResxFile.accept(rootFile, false);
            loadResxFile.accept(targetFile, true);
            normalizeTargetLocale();
            presenter.onParseCompletion();
        };
        fileOperationService.submit(buildDocument);
    }

    private void normalizeTargetLocale() {
        List<Element> translationElements = translationDocument
                .getRootElement().getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);
        Set<String> passedKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        Iterator<Element> it = translationElements.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Element el = it.next();
            String key = el.getAttribute(KEY_NAME).getValue();
            if (!originalLocale.containsKey(key)) {
                // LIVE COLLECTION!!
                it.remove();
                continue;
            }
            passedKeys.add(key);
        }

        // build new elements for newly created keys in root
        originalLocale
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(k -> !passedKeys.contains(k))
                .forEach(
                        k -> {
                            Element newElement = new Element(ELEMENT_NAME);
                            Element valueContainer = new Element(VALUE_NAME);
                            valueContainer.setText(originalLocale.get(k));

                            newElement.setAttribute(KEY_NAME, k);
                            newElement.addContent(valueContainer);
                            translationDocument.getRootElement().addContent(
                                    newElement);
                        });
    }

    private String fileNameString(final String localeIdent) {
        return String.format(FILE_NAME_FORMAT, localeIdent.isEmpty() ? "" : "."
                + localeIdent.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Translation> getTranslations() {
        List<Element> translationElements = translationDocument
                .getRootElement().getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);

        return translationElements.stream().map(el -> {
            final String key = el.getAttribute(KEY_NAME).getValue();
            final String currentValue = el.getChildText(VALUE_NAME);
            return new Translation(key, originalLocale.get(key), currentValue);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTranslation(final String key, final String newTranslation) {
        Element translationToUpdate = getValueElement(key);
        translationToUpdate.setText(newTranslation);
    }

    private Element getValueElement(final String key) {
        XPathExpression<Element> expression = xPathFactory.compile("/*/"
                + ELEMENT_NAME + "[@" + KEY_NAME + "='" + key + "']/"
                + VALUE_NAME, Filters.element());
        // ohh damn that's so many assumptions
        Element element = expression.evaluate(translationDocument).get(0);
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        Path outFile = currentPath.resolve(fileNameString(currentTargetLocale));

        try (OutputStream outStream = Files.newOutputStream(outFile,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            outputter.output(translationDocument, outStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            presenter.onException(e, "Could not save File");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Translation getSingleTranslation(final String key) {
        final String currentValue = getValueElement(key).getText();
        return new Translation(key, originalLocale.get(key), currentValue);
    }

}
```

This is the model-class I currently use. The whole code in it's current state can be viewed [on github](https://github.com/Vogel612/TranslationHelper/tree/05f37d13245b28ca91115313535037b804ca40a8)

What I'm worried about most in this class:

- The "state machine" I have running in `loadResxFile`
- My usage of JDOM and general Document manipulation
- Extensibility to additional resx features like Comments

As always interesting to me are comments concerning:

- Naming
- Performance
- Everything that catches your eye :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wasn't originally going to post this answer as it seems like petty things, but alas, here it is. I mean no offense by any of it, sometimes I tend to type things out to seem that way, but it's all in good spirit. :)

---

### Readability issues

I was reading through your code and couldn't figure out *why* it was so hard to read, until I realized you seem to be trying to adhere to a specific character-width policy. Let's *not* do that please.

I would also recommend standardizing your method-chaining line-breaks, method parameter line-breaks, and the like. If you're going to break one parameter on a method into a new line, do it for *all* of the parameters on that method. Likewise, if you are line-breaking one method-chain in a group, do it for *all* of the chains in that group. Otherwise, the eyes have to jump all over the place.

For example, I would rewrite:

> ```
>    try (OutputStream outStream = Files.newOutputStream(outFile,
>             StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
> ```

as:

```
    try (OutputStream outStream =
            Files.newOutputStream(
                outFile,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
```

Though, it is fairly difficult to break statements like that into multiple lines while maintaining readability, I find this **much** more readable than what is already there.

Likewise, this:

> ```
>    List<Element> translationElements = translationDocument
>             .getRootElement().getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);
> ```

would be easier to follow as:

```
    List<Element> translationElements = translationDocument
            .getRootElement()
            .getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);
```

---

I'm not sure on Java's best-practices on Lambda's, but I would try to avoid using large Lambda expressions like you have. The big ones - the 10+ liners - should be methods instead. Even the smaller 5-10 liners should be methods.

I tend to think of Lambda's as small bits of code that are too small to justify a method.

---

### On to my view of your main concerns

> What I'm worried about most in this class:
>
> - The "state machine" I have running in `loadResxFile`
> - My usage of JDOM and general Document manipulation
> - Extensibility to additional resx features like Comments

The first thing I notice is regarding point 3. You have:

```
private final Map<String, String> originalLocale = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And

```
                        originalLocale.put(element.getAttribute(KEY_NAME)
                                .getValue(), element
                                .getChildText(VALUE_NAME));
```

Which indicate that the only intent was to place only the Key/Value pair in the list.

Personally, I would create a class to represent a `LanguageValue` or similar.

```
public class LanguageValue {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Obviously this bit is easy, but then you should have a method (or for ease-of-use a constructor) in it:

```
public LanguageValue(Element element) {
    key = element.getAttribute(KEY_NAME).getValue();
    value = element.getChildText(VALUE_NAME);
}
```

And move the following into it:

```
private static final String VALUE_NAME = "value";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
```

Then, it **should** (if my Java is correct) be as simple as:

```
            translationElements.stream().forEach(
                    element -> {
                        originalLocale.put(new LanguageValue(element));
                    });
```

Which can simplify to (courtesy of Vogel612 in chat):

```
translationElements.stream()
    .map(LanguageValue::new)
    .forEach(originalLocale::put);
```

This will make it significantly easier to add support for additional properties in the XML. Comments, etc. (Not sure what else you would need, but it's a start.)

I would also change:

```
private final Map<String, String> originalLocale = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

To:

```
private final List<LanguageValue> originalLocale = new List<LanguageValue>();
```

There's no need for a `String` key here, as Lambda's can take care of that.

(Obviously there's more to change than just these few lines to change this feature, but hopefully it's helpful.)

---

Regarding the `loadResxFile`, I would consider moving a lot of that method to inside `LanguageValue`, as a `static` method. Or at least this bit:

```
            List<Element> translationElements = doc.getRootElement()
                    .getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);

            translationElements.stream().forEach(
                    element -> {
                        originalLocale.put(element.getAttribute(KEY_NAME)
                                .getValue(), element
                                .getChildText(VALUE_NAME));
                    });
```

You can pass `doc` as a parameter to it, and have it return a `List<LanguageValue>` back to your `loadResxFile` method. Then you can also move the following constant into `LanguageValue` as well:

```
private static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "data";
```

The idea with these last two suggestions is that `OverviewModelImpl` doesn't really need to *care* how the XML is structured for each `LanguageValue`, it only needs to care about how to get the document to `LanguageValue` for construction of the `List<LanguageValue>`.

---

I don't notice anything *glaring* about your document manipulation, other than one concern about this:

```
    XPathExpression<Element> expression = xPathFactory.compile("/*/"
            + ELEMENT_NAME + "[@" + KEY_NAME + "='" + key + "']/"
            + VALUE_NAME, Filters.element());
```

I don't like that at all. It just seems, wrong, somewhere. I'm not sure *how* it could be better, but that bit seems less-than-ideal.

Answer (score 6):

Your naming seems inconsistent.

```
public interface OverviewView {
    void register(OverviewPresenter p);
    void initialize();
    void show();
    void rebuildWith(List<Translation> translations);
    void showError(String title, String errorMessage);
}
```

You have both a `show()` and a `showError(String title, String errorMessage)` in the same interface. Does `show()` show everything except errors? Everything including errors? If `showError` as a `showX` construct as name, I'd assume all `show` variants to use a `showX` construct.

`rebuildWith(List<Translation> translations)` has a name indicating you're rebuilding the interface with something. The input seems to indicate it's rebuilding with a translation. Why doesn't the name reflect it's about translations? `rebuildWithTranslation` or `rebuildInLanguage` would be unambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few minor things, nothing too serious, that I feel can be improved.

### Java 8

From a Java 8 perspective, you have a function with significant side effects, which is bad practice. The `loadResxFile` modifies state outside the function which makes it a poor practice. Instead of modifying `originalLocale`, you should return a clean `Map` with the right values applied. If you need to merge that Map with `originalLocale` afterwards then use `originalLocale.putAll(loadedMap);`.

Additionally, you have some blocks where too much functionality is happening in one place.

Personally, I am not a huge fan of declaring concrete instances of Lambda-based constructs in Java too. I feel that if you have something like `private final BiConsumer<....> varName = {....};` that you are doing something wrong. It restricts the application of the logic too much, and it is what I personally consider to be an anti-pattern (though it is too early in Java8 'practices' to say that's a common thought process.

As another criticism, your exception handling can be improved. Why the `catch (Exception e)` ....? Any time I see that I wonder what the programmer is thinking..... On that topic, when you report an error, you should at least try to help the user by identifying what file failed to parse. "Unspecified parsing error" with a stack trace does not help the user to identify which file failed.

For example, taking this code:

> ```
> private final BiConsumer<Path, Boolean> loadResxFile = (path, isTarget) -> {
>     SAXBuilder documentBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
>     try {
>         if (isTarget) {
>             this.translationDocument = documentBuilder.build(path.toFile());
>         } else {
>             Document doc = documentBuilder.build(path.toFile());
>             List<Element> translationElements = doc.getRootElement()
>                     .getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME);
>
>             translationElements.stream().forEach(
>                     element -> {
>                         originalLocale.put(element.getAttribute(KEY_NAME)
>                                 .getValue(), element
>                                 .getChildText(VALUE_NAME));
>                     });
>         }
>     } catch (JDOMException e) {
>         this.presenter.onException(e, "Unspecified Parsing error");
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         this.presenter.onException(e, "Unspecified I/O Error");
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         this.presenter.onException(e, "Something went really wrong");
>     }
> };
> ```

I would break that down in to multiple methods:

```
private static final Document parseFile(Path xmlFile) {
    SAXBuilder documentBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    try {
        return documentBuilder.build(path.toFile());
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        this.presenter.onException(e, "Unspecified Parsing error processing " + xmlFile);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to parse " + xmlFile + " as XML", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.presenter.onException(e, "Unspecified I/O Error reading " + xmlFile);
        throw new UncheckedIOException("Unable to read " + xmlFile, e);
    }
}
```

Now, that's a method that wraps up the not-so-convenient Exceptions that JDOM throws when there's a problem (Exception handling in Streams is going to be an ongoing PITA in Java - how to handle checked exceptions...?)

That method has a different behaviour to your code, it throws an exception if there's a problem, but it also alerts the presentation layer. I am not certian that's what you would want, so remove the onException calls if necessary.

Note how it is a traditional method. This allows the logic to be easily called from either a Stream, or traditional context.

If you want, you can also:

```
private final Function<Path, Document> parser = path -> parseFile(path);
```

or:

```
private final Function<Path, Document> parser = OverviewModelImpl::parseFile;
```

Now, having stripped the complicated exception handling from the main part of the code, the rest becomes significantly simpler....

A second method would be useful for converting a document to a map of translation elements:

```
private final Map<String, String> extractTranslations(Document doc) {
    Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<>();
    doc.getRootElement().getChildren(ELEMENT_NAME)
            .stream()
            .forEach(e -> result.put(e.getAttributeValue(KEY_NAME), e.getChildText(VALUE_NAME)));
    return result;
}
```

Note the short-cut of using `getAttributeValue(...)` instead of `getAttribute(...).getValue()`. You can use this shortcut in a few places.

With the above changes, your main build code changes from:

> ```
>     Runnable buildDocument = () -> {
>         originalLocale.clear();
>         loadResxFile.accept(rootFile, false);
>         loadResxFile.accept(targetFile, true);
>         normalizeTargetLocale();
>         presenter.onParseCompletion();
>     };
>     fileOperationService.submit(buildDocument);
> ```

to be:

```
    fileOperationService.submit(() -> {
        translationDocument = parseFile(targetFile);
        originalLocale.clear();
        originalLocale.putAll(extractTranslations(parseFile(rootFile));
        normalizeTargetLocale();
        presenter.onParseCompletion();
    });
```

Note how the explicit `Runnable` declaration has been removed.

Note also how there's now no need to call the 'accept' methods directly on the BiConsumer, and the multi-stage process on the `rootFile` is now very obvious.

It's all a bunch clearer. You were creating lambda's, and then using them in a back-ported way by calling the 'accept' method. Now it's just plain non-lambda calls, for non-lambda methods.

### XPath

Your xpath method:

> ```
> private Element getValueElement(final String key) {
>     XPathExpression<Element> expression = xPathFactory.compile("/*/"
>             + ELEMENT_NAME + "[@" + KEY_NAME + "='" + key + "']/"
>             + VALUE_NAME, Filters.element());
>     // ohh damn that's so many assumptions
>     Element element = expression.evaluate(translationDocument).get(0);
>     return element;
> }
> ```

is an interesting one. It may, or may not be more complicated to consider, but XPaths can be compiled, and reused. You can also have variables on them. I would consider the following:

```
private final XPathExpression<Element> valueExpression = xPathFactory.compile(
           "/*/" + ELEMENT_NAME + "[@" + KEY_NAME + "= $key ]/"
            + VALUE_NAME, Filters.element(), Collections.singletonMap("key", ""));
```

Note the above creates the `$key` variable in the XPath expression, and sets it's value initially to "".

```
private Element getValueElement(final String key) {
    valueExpression.setVariable("key", key);
    return valueExpression.evaluateFirst(translationDocument);
}
```

Then, the above code changes the value of that variable, runs the expression, and returns the first Element. That last part is double-important. The `evaluateFirst` call is much better than `evaluate(...).get(0)` because the `evaluateFirst` does two things: it stops searching when the first instance is found so it is faster; it also does not throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception if there is no result (instead it returns null).

### Other

Otherwise, I can't see anything else that's 'off' with the JDOM usage. Using some short-cut methods will help, the evaluateFirst XPath method is important.

I like how you have used the live-iterator code for manipulating the document. As an aside, I like using a for-loop with Iterators. Where you have:

> ```
> Iterator<Element> it = translationElements.iterator();
>
> while (it.hasNext()) {
>     Element el = it.next();
>     ....
> }
> ```

I would instead consider:

```
for (Iterator<Element> it = translationElements.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Element el = it.next();
    .....
}
```

The benefit there is that the `it` variable is limited in scope to just the loop (and is not in scope afterwards). Note the 'empty' third-clause of the for loop.